# Terminal bash & zsh /user/xx/xx : not found (mac Monterey)

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, zsh, rvm

I'm very new with all this stuff can you help me fix it ?

---------------------what I see--------------------------------

**this is what I see on **bash termnial** :**

```
bash: rbenv: command not found
bash: eva: command not found
bash: rbenv: command not found
bash: Source: command not found

The default interactive shell is now zsh.
To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.
For more details, please visit https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208050.
MacBook-Pro-de-ta:~ ta$ chsh -s /bin/zsh
Changing shell for ta.
Password for ta: 
chsh: no changes made
MacBook-Pro-de-ta:~ ta$
```

**this is what i see on zsh terminal :**

```
/Users/ta/.zshrc:3: /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/ta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/bin:/Users/ta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4@global/bin:/Users/ta/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.4/bin:/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:/Users/ta/.rvm/bin not found
```

**I did this command too** :

```
ta@MacBook-Pro-de-ta ~ % zsh --version
zsh 5.8 (x86_64-apple-darwin21.0)
```

```
ta@MacBook-Pro-de-ta ~ % bash --version 
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin21)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

```
ta@MacBook-Pro-de-ta ~ % /Users/ta/.bash_profile
zsh: permission denied: /Users/ta/.bash_profile
```

```
ta@MacBook-Pro-de-ta ~ % /Users/ta/.zsh_profile
zsh: no such file or directory: /Users/ta/.zsh_profile
```

--------------------------------------- What I did ----------------------------------

-->I ran **brew cleanup** :

```
"brew doctor && brew cleanup && source ~/.zshrc"
```

-->I ran

```
brew install zsh-completions
```

nothing works ...

Comment: Please, never show text with images. They are not searchable, not copy-paste-able and much heavier than needed. Moreover they affect accessibility negatively. Please copy-paste the text in your question and [format it properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), instead.

Comment: Thanks to let me know